# Jquery knob reset on page change in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using the super jquery knob plugin http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

However, I'm triggering a manual page change inside **JQM** like so:

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer(
 'change', '#page1', {
                      transition: 'slide',
                      allowSamePageTransition: true
                     }
 );
```

Whilst I can set the value of the knob dial through a simple `.val('1')` the actual dial itself doesn't correspond to the appropriate value. The dials do refresh on a full page refresh though as you can see if you visit the above link play with a couple and refresh the page.

How can I "**reset**" the dials in JQM when manually triggering a pagechange?

Comment: You should create a small jsFiddle example of your code, this way we can solve your problem immediately. Or you should add enough of your code here so we can understand what you have done and what is the problem.

Comment: you can use any of [pageContainer events](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/). Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2ar3J/).